# Singular Value Decomposition & Compression

Tags: linear-algebra

What happen when we cancel some singular values in order to compress something?
How we compress it in this way ?

Comment: I have not had enough experience with practical applications of the SVD, but [this slide show](http://www.columbia.edu/itc/applied/e3101/SVD_applications.pdf) provides the basic idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A = U \Sigma V^*$ be an SVD of $A$ and let $\widetilde{A} = U \widetilde{\Sigma} V^*$. Take a look at Frobenius norm of $A - \widetilde{A}$:

$$\|A - \widetilde{A}\| = \sqrt{\sum_k(\Sigma_k - \widetilde{\Sigma}_k)^2}.$$

If we want $\widetilde{A}$ to have rank $\widetilde{r} < \mathop{\rm rank} A$, while minimizing $\|A - \widetilde{A}\|$, how do we achieve that?

> We create $\widetilde{\Sigma}$ from $\Sigma$ by replacing the smallest singular values by zero, thus getting $\|A - \widetilde{A}\|$ to be the square root of the sum of squares of those.

The idea here is to lose some information by dropping the rank, which requires less data to be saved, while disturbing the input as little as possible (in terms of the Frobenius norm).

I suggest reading Martin and Porter, "[The Extraordinary SVD](http://arxiv.org/abs/1103.2338)".